# Comparing text files with Junit

Tags: java, junit, compare, text-files

I am comparing text files in junit using:

```
public static void assertReaders(BufferedReader expected,
          BufferedReader actual) throws IOException {
    String line;
    while ((line = expected.readLine()) != null) {
        assertEquals(line, actual.readLine());
    }

    assertNull("Actual had more lines then the expected.", actual.readLine());
    assertNull("Expected had more lines then the actual.", expected.readLine());
}
```

Is this a good way to compare text files?  What is preferred?

Comment: I'm giving an upvote for the solution you have in the question. Since this is an older post, JUnit add ons is out of date (probably not compatible with JUnit 4), I don't like Apache Utils and given how concise your assertReaders method is I don't see justification for including a whole new library of utilities. Yours worked right off the bat - thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[junit-addons](http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit-addons) has nice support for it: [FileAssert](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/FileAssert.html)

It gives you exceptions like:

```
junitx.framework.ComparisonFailure: aa Line [3] expected: [b] but was:[a]
```

Comment: Just a note the latest version vin maven central repo is from 2003 and version 1.4 so i don't know if its compatible with the latest versions.

Answer (score 52):

Here's one simple approach for checking if the files are *exactly* the same:

```
assertEquals("The files differ!", 
    FileUtils.readFileToString(file1, "utf-8"), 
    FileUtils.readFileToString(file2, "utf-8"));
```

Where `file1` and `file2` are `File` instances, and [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Not much own code for you to maintain, which is always a plus. :) And very easy if you already happen to use Apache Commons in your project. But no nice, detailed error messages like in [mark's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466841/comparing-text-files-w-junit#466872).

**Edit**:
Heh, looking closer at the `FileUtils` API, there's an even [simpler way](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29):

```
assertTrue("The files differ!", FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2));
```

As a bonus, this version works for all files, not just text.

Comment: The assertTrue form is concise, but relatively useless when it fails.  At least the assertEquals method will show you a few characters where they are different

Comment: **Update**: Nowadays I'd recommend [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) over Commons IO for reading the files as string: `Files.toString(file1, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` There isn't much difference in a case like this, but overall Guava is a cleaner, better documented and actively maintained library.

Comment: And since **Java 7** you can [read a text file as string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/56285) quite simply without any external libs:  
 `new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 27):

Here is a more exhaustive list of File comparator's in various 3rd-party Java libraries:

- [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/thirdparty/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)
- [org.dbunit.util.FileAsserts](http://www.dbunit.org/cobertura/org.dbunit.util.FileAsserts.html)
- [org.fest.assertions.FileAssert](http://easytesting.org/assert/apidocs/org/fest/assertions/FileAssert.html)
- [junitx.framework.FileAssert](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/FileAssert.html)
- [org.springframework.batch.test.AssertFile](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/test/AssertFile.html)
- [org.netbeans.junit.NbTestCase](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-nbjunit/org/netbeans/junit/NbTestCase.html#assertFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)
- [org.assertj.core.api.FileAssert](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#file-content-string-assertions)

Comment: Sweet overview! Spared me the websearch if spring has something included ;)

Answer (score 24):

As of 2015, I would recomment [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html), an elegant and comprehensive assertion library. For files, you can assert against another file:

```
@Test
public void file() {
    File actualFile = new File("actual.txt");
    File expectedFile = new File("expected.txt");
    assertThat(actualFile).hasSameTextualContentAs(expectedFile);
}
```

or against inline strings:

```
@Test
public void inline() {
    File actualFile = new File("actual.txt");
    assertThat(linesOf(actualFile)).containsExactly(
            "foo 1",
            "foo 2",
            "foo 3"
    );
}
```

The failure messages are very informative as well. If a line is different, you get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
File:
  <actual.txt>
and file:
  <expected.txt>
do not have equal content:
line:<2>, 
Expected :foo 2
Actual   :foo 20
```

and if one of the files has more lines you get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
File:
  <actual.txt>
and file:
  <expected.txt>
do not have equal content:
line:<4>,
Expected :EOF
Actual   :foo 4
```

Comment: The method `hasContentEqualTo` is deprecated as of this comment. Use `hasSameContentAs` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Simple comparison of the content of two files with `java.nio.file` API.

```
byte[] file1Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Path to File 1"));
byte[] file2Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Path to File 2"));

String file1 = new String(file1Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String file2 = new String(file2Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

assertEquals("The content in the strings should match", file1, file2);
```

Or if you want to compare individual lines:

```
List<String> file1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Path to File 1"));
List<String> file2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Path to File 2"));

assertEquals(file1.size(), file2.size());

for(int i = 0; i < file1.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println("Comparing line: " + i)
   assertEquals(file1.get(i), file2.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest using Assert.assertThat and a [hamcrest matcher](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) (junit 4.5 or later - perhaps even 4.4).

I'd end up with something like:

```
assertThat(fileUnderTest, containsExactText(expectedFile));
```

where my matcher is:

```
class FileMatcher {
   static Matcher<File> containsExactText(File expectedFile){
      return new TypeSafeMatcher<File>(){
         String failure;
         public boolean matchesSafely(File underTest){
            //create readers for each/convert to strings
            //Your implementation here, something like:
              String line;
              while ((line = expected.readLine()) != null) {
                 Matcher<?> equalsMatcher = CoreMatchers.equalTo(line);
                 String actualLine = actual.readLine();
                 if (!equalsMatcher.matches(actualLine){
                    failure = equalsMatcher.describeFailure(actualLine);
                    return false;
                 }
              }
              //record failures for uneven lines
         }

         public String describeFailure(File underTest);
             return failure;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Matcher pros:

- Composition and reuse
- Use in normal code as well as test

  - Collections
  - Used in mock framework(s)
  - Can be used a general predicate function
- Really nice log-ability
- Can be combined with other matchers and descriptions and failure descriptions are accurate and precise

Cons:

- Well it's pretty obvious right?  This is way more verbose than assert or junitx (for this particular case)
- You'll probably need to include the hamcrest libs to get the most benefit

Answer (score 5):

`FileUtils` sure is a good one. Here's yet another [simple approach](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#checksumCRC32%28java.io.File%29) for checking if the files are exactly the same.

```
assertEquals(FileUtils.checksumCRC32(file1), FileUtils.checksumCRC32(file2));
```

While the assertEquals() does provide a little more feedback than the assertTrue(), the result of checksumCRC32() is a long. So, that may not be intrisically helpful.

Comment: +1, I guess this could come in handy for really large files (when you only care about whether the files differ, not what the difference is)

Answer (score 4):

If expected has more lines than actual, you'll fail an assertEquals before getting to the assertNull later.

It's fairly easy to fix though:

```
public static void assertReaders(BufferedReader expected,
    BufferedReader actual) throws IOException {
  String expectedLine;
  while ((expectedLine = expected.readLine()) != null) {
    String actualLine = actual.readLine();
    assertNotNull("Expected had more lines then the actual.", actualLine);
    assertEquals(expectedLine, actualLine);
  }
  assertNull("Actual had more lines then the expected.", actual.readLine());
}
```

Comment: I like that your answer doesn't rely on any third party libraries but this code won't compile.  The scope of the variable 'actual' is limited to the while-loop so the final assertNull line won't compile.

Comment: @buzz3791: No, the scope of `actualLine` is limited to the while loop. The scope of `actual` is the whole method.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own implementation of `equalFiles`, no need to add any library to your project.

```
private static boolean equalFiles(String expectedFileName,
        String resultFileName) {
    boolean equal;
    BufferedReader bExp;
    BufferedReader bRes;
    String expLine ;
    String resLine ;

    equal = false;
    bExp = null ;
    bRes = null ;

    try {
        bExp = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(expectedFileName));
        bRes = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resultFileName));

        if ((bExp != null) && (bRes != null)) {
            expLine = bExp.readLine() ;
            resLine = bRes.readLine() ;

            equal = ((expLine == null) && (resLine == null)) || ((expLine != null) && expLine.equals(resLine)) ;

            while(equal && expLine != null)
            {
                expLine = bExp.readLine() ;
                resLine = bRes.readLine() ; 
                equal = expLine.equals(resLine) ;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (bExp != null) {
                bExp.close();
            }
            if (bRes != null) {
                bRes.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    return equal;

}
```

And to use it just use regular `AssertTrue` JUnit method

```
assertTrue(equalFiles(expected, output)) ;
```