# How can i test Save methode?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a following save method, but I dont know how to verify this method. How can i verify it in JUnit ??

```
public static void save(Spiel spielen,File file ) {
    try(ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {

        out.writeObject(spielen);

        System.out.println("Speichern Erfolgreich");
        System.out.println();
    }
    catch (Exception  e) {
        System.out.println("Fehler beim Speichern");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing text files with Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466841/comparing-text-files-with-junit)

Comment: Remember that you can not test a flow which it contains an initialization with "new" statement.

Comment: @EmreSavcı that is simply not true. One could pass in the name of a temp file and write to the real file system. Or use powermock (don't do that) to mock new().

Comment: Unrelated: don't just print "error happened"! At least include the exception. You are throwing away all knowledge about the error that happened here.

Comment: @vlumi he serializes to binary. That is a bad start to duplicate with "how to compare text files"!

Comment: @GhostCat The accepted answer there supports binary files, too

Comment: @vlumi that is not at all obvious. And it adds another dependency.

Comment: @GhostCat then it would be integration test, not unit test.

Comment: @EmreSavcı I don't see requirements that the test would need to be a unit test? I do like pure functions like anyone else, but sticking to it does complicate file output tests like this.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution: don't pass in a file object. But instead a *factory* that creates an OutputStream for you.

At runtime, this could be a FileOutputStream. But for testing, you could pass a different factory that creates, say a ByteArrayOutputStream. Then your code writes to memory without knowing it.

And then you could write another test that reads back these bytes.

Comment: First of all thank you for your feedback. But unfortunately I did not understand what to write?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the reference, expected output file on the disk, and then compare the tested output against that. There are many ways to do that comparison, including some [JUnit Addons](https://sourceforge.net/projects/junit-addons/) (its [FileAssert](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/FileAssert.html) in particular), or just read both files into byte arrays and assert that they equal.

Many other utilities exist, some listed on this answer: [File comparator utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002527/3205558)