# How to test method which is saving file?

Tags: java, testing

As in title, let's say I have method which is saving file or throw new runtime exception. How can I write unit tests for it? What should be tested here?

Comment: Please provide us with your work you did so far. We can only help if we get some more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary folder using [TemporaryFolder](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) (as a JUnit rule, or as separate object) and save you file there. Then you can compare content of this file with the expected data of original file.

There was [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466841/comparing-text-files-with-junit) about ways of compiring files.